# What is the difference with at(@) and without at when spotting element by XPATH?

Tags: xpath

I am trying to locate the input element below by XPATH.

```
<input type="button" value="next" name="eventName" />
```

What is the difference between those two with @ and without @?

```
//input[@type='button' AND @value='next' AND @name='eventName']

//input[@type='button' AND value='next' AND name='eventName']
```

Answer (score 3):

The `@` before a name is a shorthand for `attribute::`, i.e. you have to use it for the `value="next"` in your example. Otherwise, it would be interpreted as an element name and not matched, as the input has no subelements.

```
<input value="next">                ->  //input[@value="next"]
<input><value>next</value></input>  ->  //input[value="next"]
```